# [SQL]ERROR when importing datetime column

Tags: postgresql, datetime, date-formatting, postgresql-9.5

i'm totally new to SQL and programming in general.
i have a .csv file and i'm supposed to import the data into a "Transaction" table I created.

However,whenever i try to  import the file an error pops saying "ERROR: date/time field value out of range "15/02/2019 9:03"
HINT:Perhaps you need a different 'datestyle' setting"
What i understand is that the postgress has a specific date format,which is MM/DD/YY,and by inputing a DD/MM/YY format the ''15'' value is out of the [1,12] bounds(months).This led me to change the .csv file date format into MM/DD/YY,but nothing changed,the problem still persists.

Any ideas on what the problem  might be?
Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: what command are you using to load the csv . Please share

Comment: none,I right clicked the table and the import option.
However I know i should start using commands for import aswell, since it is required in the university project I work on.